# Introduction to Hida Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory

I know that the obvious references to learn Hida theory are this own (difficult) papers. I`ve looked online for other sources but only found summaries which are too short.

Does anybody know of lecture notes or a learning seminar on Hida theory where one can learn the main ideas? Or some video lectures similar to the Arizona Winter School lectures?

Comment: I found that looking at www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/papers/Hida.August11.pdf together with Hida's book "Elementary Theory of L-functions and Eisenstein Series" was a good start. The notes are quite nice for an overview and the book is a bit easier to read than the papers. Although, I would say, if you want to do this stuff properly, then putting more time into his papers is a good idea.

Comment: I`m aware of those references, thanks. Ideally, I`d like to find a series of lecture notes or of a learning seminar aimed at phd students.

Comment: Have you tried Gouvea's book "Arithmetic of p-adic modular forms"? It's mostly about the (historically earlier) Katz/Serre approach but there are some parts about Hida theory too.

Comment: Hadn`t thought of Gouvea`s book. Will look into it.

Comment: Hello pedro, just a note for the layout of your texts: the apostrophe `'` is used for , well apostrophing, like `I'm` . On german keyboard it is on the `#` key. What you used for it is the back-quote `\`` but which tells the system to put the following text down to the next back-quote in grey and monospace-font. So this back-quote makes "Hadn`t thought of Gouvea`s book." instead of "Hadn't thought of Gouvea's book."